# i want a x86 file to run in aarch64

Tags: compiling, x86, arm64

I wanted to play osu lazor, so I downloaded the appimage file from  [their GitHub releases](https://github.com/ppy/osu/releases) and tried to run. However, when I tried to run the game with `./osu.AppImage`, It said

```
-bash: ./osu.AppImage: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I found out that this error occurs because the format of the file is different. The format of the game is

```
$ file osu.AppImage 
osu.AppImage: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
```

And my computer's format is `aarch64`.

I had two options

1. run the game in emulator
2. recompile

I don't want to run an emulator since the game will probably get slow.

In conclusion, I want to recompile the game that works in `aarch64`, but I have no idea how to do it.

If you think running the game on the emulator(such as qemu) is the better option, please advise me.

There is the source code in GitHub too.

Comment: What you should do is compile it from source, or find an aarch64 build. You can also try [Box86](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86), but this is a really bad way to do it when you have the source code.

Comment: Yes I want to compile the game from the source. But how? I haven't used a compiler exept g++. There are so many files and I don't know what to do